# MYSQL limit is slow

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-administration

I have this query running against 15000 records

```
SELECT t.*, concat(t.address1, ', ',t.zip, ' ',t.city, ', ',c.countryName ) AS fullAddress
FROM `User` `t` INNER JOIN
     Country c
     ON t.countryCode = c.countryCode
WHERE (userType != -1 AND userType != 1 AND address1 IS NOT NULL AND zip IS NOT NULL AND city IS NOT NULL AND t.countryCode IS NOT NULL
      ) AND
       (concat( t.address1, ', ', t.zip, ' ', t.city, ', ', c.countryName ) regexp '^[0-9]+,? [^,]+, [0-9]+,? [^,]+, [a-zA-Z]+$')
LIMIT 1000
```

When I remove the limit 1000 part, it returns the result quickly, but with the limit 1000 it takes a lot of time. and phpmyadmin gets stuck

the table structure is as below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `User` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `address1` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `mobile` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1 - female, 2-male, 0 - unknown',
  `zip` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `countryCode` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `joinedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `signUpDate` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'User signed up date',
  `supporterDate` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'Date which user get supporter',
  `userType` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4' COMMENT 'Type of user. 1 - Politician 2 - Supporter 3 - Prospects 4 - Non support 5 - Unknown 6 - Newsletter 7 - Petitioner',
  `signup` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'whether user followed signup process 1 - signup, 0 - not signup',
  `isSysUser` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1 - system user, 0 - not a system user',
  `dateOfBirth` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'User date of birth',
  `reqruiteCount` int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'User count that he has reqruited',
  `keywords` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT 'Kewords',
  `delStatus` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 - active, 1 - deleted',
  `city` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `longLat` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Longitude and Latitude',
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;



ALTER TABLE `User`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `email` (`email`),
  ADD KEY `cindex` (`countryCode`);
```

How can I improve this query ?

Comment: This seems unlikely.  Are you sure you don't have an `order by` along with the `limit`?

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` the `LIMIT` doesn't make much sense - you can't easily influence what MySQL decides to send you.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no there is order by

Comment: @dev1234 - your query shown above does *not* currently contain an `ORDER BY` clause, and like others have said, that really makes a difference with `LIMIT` and your question in general.  Please clarify how you are sorting the records within the result set, and you will get a better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think that the following line:

```
AND (concat( t.address1, ', ', t.zip, ' ', t.city, ', ', c.countryName ) regexp '^[0-9]+,? [^,]+, [0-9]+,? [^,]+, [a-zA-Z]+$')
```

is causing your bottleneck. I would suggest removing that line and running the query to see how much that improves your performance. If that indeed is the bottleneck, here are some possible actions you could take:

- Validate the data on insert, so all data is valid.
- If your database should accept invalid addresses, you could create a `IS_VALID_ADDRESS` boolean column.
- You could make one or both of the columns above a `GENERATED` column and ensure it is `STORED`

Comment: Yup that would turn it into a table scan, of course I wonder why he is looking for invalid characters at query time and not excluding them on entry. Perhaps there is more to this question.

Comment: @Randall . . . A table scan on 15,000 records is not likely to take "a lot of time" causing PHP to get stuck -- unless the OP has a really, really short attention span.  It might make the difference between a fraction of a second and few seconds, but this answer seems irrelevant, because the OP claims that the `where` clause remains the same.  In addition, comparing each column separately using `regexp` would be about the same amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add index to column, this will improve the result.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail on why an index will improve the speed, as well as how to add an index?

Comment: how to add an index : CREATE UNIQUE INDEX server_id on servers (server_id);

Comment: please follow the official link, why an index will improve the speed : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html